# Can cx-freeze be used in Ubuntu to freeze a python script to a Windows executable?

Tags: python, cx-freeze

When I use cxfreeze in Ubuntu, it automatically compiles the python script to a Linux executable. I've looked through the documentation extensively, and I can't find a way to freeze the script into a .exe for the purposes of running the program on a Windows machine. Can this be done-?

Comment: You'd probably be better off installing the correct versions of your dependencies on a Windows machine and then running cxfreeze there. They have a downloaable [Windows installer](http://cx-freeze.sourceforge.net/) for Pythons 2.5-3.2, x86/x32.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that.... but you'll have to install Wine (apt-get install wine) and then install in Wine the windows version of Python and all the python libraries your application needs, and then you'll be able to freeze your script into an exe for windows in your ubuntu box.

Comment: Thanks - I want to vote this up but it's telling me I can't until I have a certain amount of reputation.